# ERROR in install opencv in my python 3.6.6

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I HAVE PYTHON 3.6.6 INSTALLED IN MY WINDOWS 7 PLATFORM BUT WHEN I TRIED TO INSTALL OPENCV PACKAGE IT SAYS REQUIREMENT ALREADY SATISFIED AND IF I TRY TO IMPORT CV2 IT SAYS NO MODULE .I'VE TRIED ALL POSSIBLE METHODS ON INTERNET WHAT SHOULD I DO

i tried to download opencv exe from sourceforge and copying cv2.pyd file and then pasting it in site packages

i tried pip install opencv_python-4.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

but nothing works

Comment: Show us the exact error messages. It is likely that you have 2 Python environments and your pip command installed cv2 in the one you were not expecting.

Comment: opencv_python-4.0.0.21-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform error when i try to installopen cv on python3.6.6 will open cv support 3.6.6 version @BoarGules

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are asking PIP install a version of `cv2` for 64-bit Python 2.7, and that installation is *failing*. So the installation is not happening because it's the wrong version. That might be because you don't have Python 2.7, or because you have a 32-bit processor, or both. Navigate to `Python36\Scripts` and issue the command `pip install opencv_python`. Then `pip` will find the appropriate file to download, and install it.